# Get the current item id in visual studio workflow

Tags: workflow, tasks, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a Visual Studio workflow. It's creating a task to the user when 
`Status.Equal("New")`.

I need a link in task mail body which will redirect to the current item. How can this be done?

[image: Email]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Get the standard url of the items for the list like below example

```
 http://host/sites/sitecollection/list_name/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
```

Here at end you can replace the id (in this case 1) of the current item using properties and form string like above url and place it in email.

Comment: I given it like 'https://aufaitcloud.sharepoint.com/sites/APPSTEST/ERecruitment/lists/JobRequisition/EditForm.aspx?ID= after ID how can i set the current item ID in visual studio??

Comment: anyone knows about this,, please help me